# Show ASP.NET User Control in SharePoint?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls

I have been given the task to create a "Web Part" for a `Sharepoint` website. The reason i quote "Web Part" is because i don't think that it suits my needs.

With a `User Control` a developer is absolutely free in what kind of control he wants to add. This can easily be done in the (for example) `MyUserControl.aspx` file from the `MyUserControl.ascx` control. You can even add jQueryUI elements to the `User Control` like tabs etc.

So basically i need to be free in what kind of (HTML) elements i add to the page and what not.

Since it looks like this can't be achieved with a SharePoint `Web Part` i want to know if it is possible to display a `User Control` instead?

Is there a way to do this..??

Comment: What can you add to UC and you can not add to WP?

Comment: @banana Well as far as i can see i can only add controls through code in a `Web Part`. I want to be able to fully customize the look and feel of the "page" or "web part" that i add in SharePoint. So basically i just want to add a web page to my SharePoint site. But i need to add Report Viewer control to the page. Custom textfields to filter the data in there. And text fields to add data back to the datebase. This would be no problem when i create an ASP Web App. But i'm not sure how to integrate this in a SharePoint site...

Comment: You can add any control through code in a Web Part. What do you mean by "fully customize the look and feel"? you want the markup?

Comment: @banana Yes i also need to add markup, like `CSS`. How else am i going to properly align and style my `textfields` and `dropdowns` etc? I also need to use a few `jQueryUI` widgets. This is no problem when i develop a normal website. I just have no idea how to create such a web page in SharePoint. It seems to me that this isn't possible from a SharePoint `Web Part`.

Comment: First of all - I think that good design is to give each control [CssClass](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_style_cssclass.asp) and link (in Master Page) css file. As for the html tags you want to add - I think my answer below answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `User control` directly to a specific SharePoint page, but you can add to Master Page or Page Layout. (And only by SharePoint designer)

Another option is to create `User Control` add load it to `Web Part`, and add the `Web Part` to your page.

**Edit:**

As Rikard Uppström wrote, in VS2010 there is template named Visual Web Part that does exactly that for you, but if you work in SP 2007 you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio you can select "Create new Visual WebPart", provided it is SharePoint 2010 we are talking about?
This option gives you a ascx-file which you can treat like a normal usercontrol. It is automatically wrapped as a SharePoint-webpart.

See this walkthrough for more thorough information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/01/28/creating-a-sharepoint-visual-web-part-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx